# unable to change the background color in Angular using style binding

Tags: angular

The background color of the `div` is not changing when using the style binding using Angular.The code is placed below for reference

```
@Component({
  selector: 'course',
  template: `
   <div [style.backgroundColor]='red'>

   <button (click)="onClick($event)" class="btn btn-primary" [class.active]="isActive" [style.backgroundColor]='red'>Save</button>
   </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./course.component.css']
  })
  export class CourseComponent {...}
```

The style element has the `backgroundColor` property. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: do it in angular way using ngStyle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular property binding expects an expression instead of a value which you are trying to assign.
Instead of `[style.backgroundColor]='red'` you might want to use `[style.backgroundColor]="'red'"` note that i have wrapped 'red' on quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've a typo in your code ..

try this:

```
 [style.background-color]="'red'"
```

.. so something like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'course',
  template: `
   <div [style.background-color]='red'>

   <button (click)="onClick($event)" class="btn btn-primary" [class.active]="isActive" [style.background-color]='red'>Save</button>
   </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./course.component.css']
  })
  export class CourseComponent {...}
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: No. Its not working. I tried `<div [style.backgroundColor]='red'>`

Comment: you have to try    <div [style.background-color]='red'> as i say

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **`[ngStyle]`** with **`backgroundColor`** property

```
<div  [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: 'red' }">
   <button (click)="onClick($event)" class="btn btn-primary" [class.active]="isActive" [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: 'red' }">Save</button>
</div>
```

**[DEMO STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c8jbnm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Broken link. I tried something like what you have with no luck.