# Changing background color in angular application

Tags: html, css, angular, angular8

I am working on an angular application. I have a css class in `div` which has general properties like `font`, `padding`, `background-color` etc. html code is something like this.

```
<div class="myCss">
  //my code
</div>
```

in CSS file, have css like this

```
div.myCss {
 color: white;
 font-size: 23px;
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

For a certain condition, I need to change `background-color`. If `myFlag` is true, I want `background-color` to be black, otherwise yellow. I tried using `ngClass`, but in that when `myFlag == true` I need to write the whole css just to change `background-color`. Is there is any way, I can only change `background-color` on the basis of flag instead of making a new css class with exact same properties as previous one's just with background color change.

2. I have table in html as follows:

   1
             2
             3
             4
             5

and in css class I have following css:

```
table th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: white;
    background-color: #002BA4;
    padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
}
```

For the same flag, I want to change `background-color` of this `th` too. How I can do this?

Comment: Code editor not showing table as mentioned in point 2. Table looks something like this.  <tr class="myCss2">
         <th>1</th>
         <th>2</th>
         <th>3</th>
         <th>4</th>
         <th>5</th>
    </tr>

Comment: This is what you're looking for: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/attribute-class-style-bindings-angular

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to change the background color in Angular using style binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850525/unable-to-change-the-background-color-in-angular-using-style-binding)

Answer (score 1):

There're two ways you could approach this:

**Option 1**

Create a variable to store the style, for example, this will allow you to be able to use this variable multiple times in your template.

```
let color = myFlag? 'black' : 'yellow';
```

then in your template, you can do this:

```
<div [className]="color"></div>
```

However, this only set the class name so you still need to style those classes.

```
.black{
   background-color: black;
}

.yellow{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

**Option 2**

You could use style binding like this:

```
<div [style.backgroundColor]="!myFlag ? 'yellow': 'black'" ></div>
```

this option will require you to write the same thing in the case where you'll be wishing to change the `background-color`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="myCss" [style.background-color]="getBackgroundColor()"> 
  //my code
</div>

<th [style.background-color]="getBackgroundColor()">1</th>
```

Please use the style attribute on div using your myFlag attribute

TS Code:
getBackgroundColor() {
return this.myFlag ? 'black': 'yellow';
}

Comment: thanks and what I can do for  that table scenario, I  mentioned in question. Any Idea?

Comment: you can do the same for <th> as well. Create a method in TS and use it in a template. I have updated my code accordingly.